# Как красиво оформить код в онлайн редакторе?

Tags: css, оформление

Возможно вопрос не по теме , но мне нужно оформить код программы / или текст , с помощью какого-то сайта красиво, вот ниже пример :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если кто-то знает такой сайт , буду благодарен)

Comment: [Выбирайте](https://www.google.com/search?q=syntax+highlighter+online)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать скриншот при помощи Carbon, скопируйте нужный код в своей IDE или редакторе кода и вставьте его в окно на сайте. Затем кликните кнопку Export в правом верхнем углу.
https://carbon.now.sh/

Comment: да ,но мне нужно для поста в Инстаграм, без заднего фона

Comment: фотошоп в помощь
или поищите что-то для себя тут - https://techrocks.ru/2019/11/17/6-ways-to-take-code-screenshots/#:~:text=%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC,A)%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82.